# Retrieve search results selenium python bs4

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I successfully put together a script to retrieve search results from sales navigator in Linkedin. The following is the script, using python, selenium, and bs4.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
url1 = "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/company?companySize=E&geoIncluded=emea%3A0%2Ceurope%3A0&industryIncluded=6&keywords=AI&page=1&searchSessionId=zreYu57eQo%2BSZiFskdWJqg%3D%3D"

browser.get(url1)
time.sleep(15)

parsed = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed, 'html.parser')

search_results = soup.select('dt.result-lockup__name a')
print(len(search_results))

time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

Irrespective of the no.of results, the answer was always 10 (i.e.) only 10 results were returned. Upon further investigation into the source, I noticed the following :

[image]

That the first 10 results are represented at a different level and the rest are under a div tag with style class named as **deferred area**. Though the **dt class name** is the same for all the search results **(result-lockup__name)**, due to the change in levels, I am not able to access/retrieve it.

What would be the right way to retrieve all results in such a case?

**EDIT 1**

An example of how the tag levels are within **li**
[image]

And an example of the html script of the result that is not being retrieved
[image]

**EDIT 2**

The page source as requested

https://pastebin.com/D11YpHGQ

Comment: what string are you entering in the search text box to generate that url?

Comment: it is linkedin sales nav search. it asks for keywords and then few filter criteria that has to be selected, after which the search results are obtained. the keyword I entered is AI.

Comment: Why don't you try to select the search results items using their class name `search-results__result-item` ??

Comment: There are many levels within that class name. The class that contains the name and the url of the companies is result-lockup__name.

Comment: can you also share the source code of the page ?

Comment: trying to. The page seems to have gone down suddenly. figuring it out. looks like they noticed someone scraping and shut it down.

Comment: @AvishekSaha please check the edit and let me know if that helps.

Comment: if you can share the source code of the page instead of the photo then I can try to check

Comment: `soup.find_all("dt", class_="result-lockup__name")` have you tried this ?

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: I tried copying the code, but it was really lengthy and I felt it would occupy more space and make reading only the important parts difficult. hence the images.

Comment: @AvishekSaha I tried that as well. Still gives 10. I tried selenium's "find elements by" for xpath, css selector etc and still got the same.

Comment: In that case I can only help you if you can share the code of the page in a pastebin @LakshmiNarayanan

Comment: so basically, the page source code as such carries not much info. But after obtaining the inner html and printing out "parsed" variable from above, I noticed that the html script presented there only had 10 search result names. and this is what is also read by bs4 and hence it returns 10.

Comment: I tried to paste the source code above, but exceeded 30,000 lines limit posed above. shall put it through pastebin

Comment: @AvishekSaha are you able to view the page source from the link pasted?

Comment: no you will need an account to access the page

Comment: I was able to access it as guest in incognito , while i was testing.

Comment: I pasted the link again. can try the new one? @AvishekSaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of sites don't display all search results on page load rather only display them when needed, e.g the visitor keeps scrolling indicating they want to view more.

We can use javascript to scroll to the bottom of the page for us `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)` , (you may want to loop this if you expect hundreds of results) forcing all results on the page, after which we can grab the HTML.

Below should do the trick.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
url1 = "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/company?companySize=E&geoIncluded=emea%3A0%2Ceurope%3A0&industryIncluded=6&keywords=AI&page=1&searchSessionId=zreYu57eQo%2BSZiFskdWJqg%3D%3D"

browser.get(url1)
time.sleep(15)
browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
time.sleep(15)

parsed = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed, 'html.parser')

search_results = soup.select('dt.result-lockup__name a')
print(len(search_results))
```